# SVG in table - Chrome, Firefox, IE

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

I have the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                        <rect width="100" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
                    </svg>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
        <rect width="100" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I rendered it in IE9, Firefox and Chrome (both the latest as of this writing). Non of them seem to get it right, and they all produce different output.

---

Here are the results:

### IE9

[image: IE9]

Notice the unexplained blank space causing the `td` to expand instead of wrapping the `svg` tightly

### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

The `td` still has an unexplained height (like IE), but a width of 0, thus leaving the `svg` to overflow

### Chrome

[image: Chrome]

This one seems the worst. The `svg` in the table is not even displayed this time!

---

So the questions are:

1. Are any of these right. I would expect the table to fully (display and) contain and tightly wrap the `svg`.
2. Why isn't Chrome even displaying the `svg` in the table?
3. Is there a workaround to get `svg` images in tables to display consistently across all three browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `<svg>` element matching `height` and `width` attributes, such as:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="50">
```

Comment: This answers #3. Any idea about #1 & #2?

Comment: Also, while it does work, this gets very tedious for a lot of svg images. Especially since the dimensions of an embedded svg are not easily found.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way things are. You need to specify the size of the viewport as well as the size and origins of all shapes and paths within the svg. The reasons browsers are showing differently is because of different default sizes for the `svg` element.